# I got lost, where should I go?

Tags: no-mans-sky, steam-vr

I took a walk in No Man's Sky in order to find Copper. I walked 5 minutes in any direction. Now I got lost and dont know in which direction I must go.

The scanner only shows resources.

Comment: It's been a good while since I've booted up NMS, but I'm fairly confident there's a persistent HUD marker to get you back to your ship?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Nope. Btw, I do play in VR. Is that an important information that I do play in VR?

Comment: I'd recommend just summoning your ship to you. Unsure of the controls in VR though.

Comment: On steam community I found that you can summon the ship on vr                        "It should be on the Quick Menu on your left hand, right by your inventory. You may need to scroll left a bit, because I think it's one of the leftmost options. (You may need to select the left most option and then go back to "scroll", because I don't think there's a way to actually scroll without selecting something)"

Answer (score 2):

In order to find previously visited place you have to place some kind of marker on it. Marker could be starship, other vehicles, registered base, save beacon, save beacon on NPC bases. Or the analysis visor shows you coordinates on the right side. (Btw. I lost some NPC's before I learnt how to use Save Beacon, it sadly happens.)

Answer (score 2):

> Now I got lost and dont know in which direction I must go.

In the immortal words of the chesire cat, "That depends a good deal on where you want to get to."

If you already have a base, there's dome shaped marker on your HUD. Your ship will also have a marker. If you don't want to walk back, just craft a new portable refiner and base computer where you are, and *viola*, you're home (technically)!